# What do the numbers in WebGL shader compile error message mean?

Tags: glsl, webgl

For example,

```
ERROR: 0:137: 'blend2' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:137: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:137: '=' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'highp 3-component vector of float'
```

What is `0` in `0:137`?
What is `137` in `0:137`?
Why is all the error messages begin with `0:`? Why isn't it `1:` or `2:`?

Note I'm not asking why I got those error. Answers with reference to some official spec or documentation are preferred if there is one. I'm using Chrome 63.0.3239.132.

Comment: "*Answers with reference to some official spec or documentation are preferred.*" Error messages are implementation-defined. There can't be references to "some official spec or documentation."

Comment: @NicolBolas Understood. I added `if there is one`.

Comment: [Here's an example of a wrapper](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/7ajksn61/) you can include in your code or put in a separete JS file and include

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is 0 in 0:137?

It's the index of the shader string that produced the error. In regular OpenGL, `glShaderSource` allows you to provide multiple strings. They are compiled as if they were concatenated together. But this means that error messages have to identify the particular string in the shader that is responsible for the error. The first number is a zero-based index into the array of strings provided to `glShaderSource`.

Of course, WebGL's equivalent `gl.shaderSource` function doesn't allow you to provide multiple shader strings. So if the WebGL implementation ultimately calls into an OpenGL or OpenGL ES implementation directly, then the errors that OpenGL produces will have the string index in them, even though they technically don't need it.

> What is 137 in 0:137?

It's the line number at which the error occurred.

Comment: But the shader only has 97 lines. What's the possible reason of a line number 137 that is bigger than 97? This is another question, though. The shader is saved in a separate .frag file.

Comment: I just figured out what had happened. I'm using three js with [`ShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/materials/ShaderMaterial) which will adds some threejs-internal statements to the shader(*Built in attributes and uniforms are passed to the shaders along with your code.*), so the line number in the shader error message is *incorrect*.

Comment: Be aware that what error message gets output and what it's format is or even if there is an error message at all is not defined by the WebGL or OpenGL ES 2.0 specs. No error messages are required. All that is required is that an invalid program fail to link (invalid shaders are allowed to compile according to the spec). That said, the majority of drivers do return values as stated in this answer.